# How do you nest React components/modules to separate the UI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I have three main components for a dashboard UI I'm working on (I'm a React beginner, coming from Angular): a sidebar, top nav, and a content container.

How would I split these into three separate UI components and call them in other components? I want to be able to do this:

```
<Sidenav /> <!-- sidenav component from Sidenav.js -->
<section className="content">
    <Topnav /> <!-- top nav component from Topnav.js -->
    <div className="wrapper container">
        <!-- Content here -->
    </div>
</section>
```

And also, how would you use the `<div className="wrapper container"></div>` as a view for all content?

I'm using ES6 and the [React Starterify](https://github.com/Granze/react-starterify) app kit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I would do it (you'll notice I name all my component files `.jsx` instead of `.js`, though it doesn't matter either way. I've even seen people do `Component.jsx.js`):

**src/index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="js/bundle.min.js"></script> <!-- I'm assuming you're using Browserify or similar to bundle the entire app into a single file -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**src/js/main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Routes} from '../components';

render(Routes, document.body);
```

**src/components/App.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import Topnav from './Topnav';

module.exports = React.createClass({
  displayName: 'App',
  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.shape({
      props: React.PropTypes.object
    })
  },
  render () {
    return (
      <section className="content">
        <Topnav />
        <div className="wrapper container">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </section>
    );
  }
});
```

`{this.props.children}` will render the component that is handling the current route.

**src/components/Topnav.jsx**

```
...
```

Think of it the same way you would create grouping in an object-oriented language like Java. Components that belong with each other should go together. So, for example, if I had to write a `Profile` component, that might look like:

```
-- src
  -- components
    -- profile
      -- index.js // Used to export Profile 
      -- Profile.jsx // This would have the profile layout and be a parent to all other components in this folder
      -- Address.jsx
      -- Gravatar.jsx
      -- ...
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!